# Problems updating using Eloquent

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

Right now I'm working on my first update function using Eloquent ORM. Trying to follow the docs, I have this in my model:

```
public function updateAvailability()
{
    $this->active = Input::get('available');
    $this->activeDetails = Input::get('availableStatus');
    $this->save();
}
```

which returns:

```
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

and all of this is being called to in my controller as:

```
public function updateProfile($id)
{
    if(Input::get('type')=='availability'){
        $availability = User::find($id)->updateAvailability;
    }
    $name = str_replace(' ', '', Input::get('name'));
    return Redirect::to('people/'.$name);
}
```

Are there some gaps in my understanding of updating in Eloquent? (I'm sure there are). I would love to use ajax to handle it, but I can't seem to find the right resources to get that working.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: $availability = User::find($id)->updateAvailability; needed to be changed to $availability = User::find($id)->updateAvailability();. That's all.